# Mapping values returns nothing in scala Flink

Tags: scala, mapping, apache-flink, kryo

I am developing a discretization algorithm in flink, but  I am having problems applying a `map` function.

The discretization is stored in `V` which is a

```
private[this] val V = Vector.tabulate(nAttrs)(i => IntervalHeap(nBins, i, s))
```

This Vector is updated in the following method:

```
private[this] def updateSamples(v: LabeledVector): Vector[IntervalHeap] = {
    val attrs = v.vector.map(_._2)
    // TODO: Check for missing values
    attrs
      .zipWithIndex
      .foreach {
        case (attr, i) =>
          if (V(i).nInstances < s) {
            V(i) insert (attr)
          } else {
            if (randomReservoir(0) <= s / (i + 1)) {
              val randVal = Random nextInt (s)
              V(i) replace (randVal, attr)
            }
          }
      }
    V
  }
```

And the map function apply to each instance of a dataset the function `updateSamples):

```
def discretize(data: DataSet[LabeledVector]) /*: DataSet[IntervalHeap]*/ = {
    val d = data map (x => updateSamples(x))
    log.debug(s"$V")
    d print
  }
```

However, when I print `d`, I get V empty:

```
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
Vector(Attr [0]         [;][;][;][;][;])
```

I've tried to not return `V` in `updateSamples` and just access it from `driscretize` once the map is applied, but the same occurs. If inside `updateSamples` I print the value of `V` I can see that its being updated.

### Update

If I don't use the container `DataSet[T]` and instead use a `Seq` like this:

```
def discretize(data: Seq[LabeledVector]) /*: DataSet[IntervalHeap]*/ = {
    data map (x => updateSamples(x))
  }
```

The discretization works fine.

What may be happening?

### Update 2

After a few days searching, It seems the problem is guava's collection `MinMaxPriorityQueue`. However, I can not found anything that helps me to Serialize this collection, here is what I've found so far:

- [How do you serialize a guava collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351587/how-do-you-serialize-a-guava-collection)
- [magro/kryo-serializers](https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers) This is a collection of serializers for guava's collections, but `MinMaxPriorityQeue` is not there
- I've tried [this](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Serialization-problem-for-Guava-s-TreeMultimap-td9054.html), which consists in registering a `kryo` Serializer `env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[MinMaxPriorityQueue[Double]], classOf[JavaSerializer])` but does not work.
- I've also tried to add a default `Kryo` serializer with no luck `env.getConfig.addDefaultKryoSerializer(classOf[MinMaxPriorityQueue[Double]], classOf[JavaSerializer])`